# Google sheets : Is there a way to prevent duplicate month entries?

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I am setting up a template in Google sheets where I need a user to enter upto 12 months balance information. Each of the 12 months should be different without any repetition. I would like to restrict the user from entering same months again as input. Is there a way to prevent entry of duplicate months? I can restrict duplicate dates using data validation but can't seem to figure out for months.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

if you want to use formula you can use [=MONTH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052?hl=en-GB) in conjuction with [=IF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en-GB)

- `=MONTH(A1)` will return a month of the cell **A1**

[image]

- `=IF(MONTH(A1 = 7), TRUE, FALSE)` will return **TRUE** if month in **A1** is **7**

[image]

---

if you want to use **Apps Script (JS)** you could try these functions:

1. [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
// edit your logic here
const monthsDone = [1,2,3,4];
if (monthsDone.includes(4)) Logger.log('Sorry, this month already exists')
```

2. [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const monthsDone = [1,2,3,4];
const myMatch = (month) => month === 4;
monthsDone.some(myMatch) // returns true if 4 exists
```

3. [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
4. [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
5. [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure how to set it as a data validation.  Can you please show how to do it in this spreadsheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W9V-Rabh1HvfikZ3iiFe6sUx5kxqlkYb7ZPZeX6tJq4/edit?usp=sharing